# which operators are correct for my command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I worked with sql server 2008 and I used this command:

```
SELECT Min(id), 
       [idfromindex] 
FROM   ordersview 
WHERE  [idfromindex] IN(SELECT DISTINCT [idfromindex] 
                        FROM   ordersview 
                        WHERE  isobserve = 'True' 
                               AND ispay = 'True' 
                               AND orderdate >= '1390/09/01' 
                               AND orderdate <= '1391/09/27') 
GROUP  BY [idfromindex]
```

But if there is a record with exactly `orderdate='1390/09/01'` or `orderdate='1391/09/27'` value it will not show them ,it only shows the result greater and lower than them but I want to show the equal one too if it exists.

orderDate type is Date

Comment: Does 'orderdate' have a time component as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't changing the condition to being `>= '1390/09/01'` and `< '1391/09/28'` make more sense? That way you remove the time components if a date is registered as being `1390/09/01 23:59'. Date conditions tend to assume the exact time is`00:00`. Of course it depends on what your column datatype is (datetime vs. date).

Comment: Actually, > '1390/08/31' should be >= '1390/09/01'.  Records timestamped '1390/08/31 xx:xx' should be excluded.

Comment: You're right, I confused myself. I changed my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**DATETIME data type contain both date and time information**

If you provide only the date part, SQL sets the time part as the beginning of the day, which is midnight...

So **Add a +1 on right or adding -1 on left** will solver your problem..

```
SELECT DISTINCT [idfromindex] 
                        FROM   ordersview 
                        WHERE  isobserve = 'True' 
                               AND ispay = 'True' 
                               AND orderdate >= dateadd(day,1,'1390/09/01')
                               AND orderdate <= dateadd(day,1,'1391/09/27')
```